# Verificar se o valor já existe no arquivo txt

Tags: java, android, eclipse

estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de inventário que em sua versão freeware irá trabalhar com os dados inseridos em um arquivo txt linha a linha, a estrutura dos dados será a seguinte

**Código de barras + Descrição + Localização** "E após localização quero colocar uma soma, em que cada vez que o mesmo código for lido ele irá somando +1 no arquivo texto"

Código de escrita;

```
 String dados;

                        //   lstrNomeArq = (txtScanResult.getText()  + ".txt");
                     File arquivo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MatheusArrudaDev/InventarioFree/" + timeStamp + "/geral.txt");

                     String unidademetalicascan = (String) txtScanResult.getText();
                     Editable localizacao =  identestoque.getText();
                     Editable descricao =  txtdescricao.getText();
                     dados = unidademetalicascan + localizacao;

                     try {

                     if (!arquivo.exists()) {
                     //cria um arquivo (vazio)
                     arquivo.createNewFile();
                     }

                     //caso seja um diretório, é possível listar seus arquivos e diretórios
                     File[] arquivos = arquivo.listFiles();

                     //escreve no arquivo
                     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);

                     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


                     bw.write(unidademetalicascan + " " + descricao +"  "+ localizacao);

                     bw.newLine();

                     bw.close();
                     fw.close();

                     //faz a leitura do arquivo
                     FileReader fr = new FileReader(arquivo);

                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                     //equanto houver mais linhas
                     while (br.ready()) {
                     //lê a proxima linha
                     String linha = br.readLine();

                     //faz algo com a linha
                     System.out.println(linha);
                     }

                     br.close();
                     fr.close();

                     } catch (IOException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();

                     }
```

**Por exemplo:**

O aplicativo leu "123" e a descrição do produto é "Creme", eu quero que ele escreva

123 Creme 1

Se ele ler 123 de novo, quero que ele Edite a linha acima e escreva

123 Creme 2.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Uma solução seria utilizar o `SQLite`, facilitaria um pouco sua vida!

[Documentação SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)
[Artigo da TutorialsPoint sobre SQLite com Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)

Uma outra solução seria carregar o conteúdo do arquivo em memória e utilizar um background worker para salvar o arquivo a cada `x` segundos por exemplo!

Espero que ajude!

Abraço

Comment: Entendo vou tentar trabalhar com o SQLite então, obrigado.